# Mount FTP so it will be possible to execute shell commands

Tags: mount, ftp, curlftpfs

I have backup storage on FTP server. I want to mount FTP server (may be with a  help of curlftpfs) ands not only read/write, but also execute shell commands there, too. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing that will mount *and* let you execute remote shell commands.

But the mounting it simple enough:

```
sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
curlftpfs ftp://username:password@server /target/
```

You can then run *local* shell commands by `cd`ing into `/target/` (obviously change that in both cases to somewhere you'd actually like to mount it) and then run whatever you want.

If you need to run *remote* FTP commands, you're best off with a proper FTP client like Filezilla.

Comment: +1 but I'm curious why you have to first `cd /target/` in order to run `ls /` why couldn't you simply type `ls /target/` and forgo `cd /target/`? I'm looking for an easy way to mount phone and stat about 3600 files (in many subdirectories under /music directory) to get last access date. This new project is what led me to your answer. I posted a question about this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178818/how-to-mount-android-external-storage-over-wifi-instead-of-usb