# How to get videos off Android phone with USB cable?

Tags: usb, files, kde, transfer

I'm on the newest KDE Ubuntu and just trying to move some large videos from the phone to my computer. The KDE connect works great but is too slow for videos.

When I connect to the phone with USB, the "Storage" folder is locked and I get the error message when I try to open the folder: Could not enter folder /media/l/disk/storage and can't open Dolphin with Sudo.

Thanks.

[image: Desktop screenshot]

Comment: Why did I get an instant downvote?

Comment: Instead of USB 2.0 which is 12 Mbps, use WiFi which is 800 Mbps on average these days. Not the perfect reference but I was working on this last week: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178818/how-to-mount-android-external-storage-over-wifi-instead-of-usb/1179873#1179873