# Transfer files from Windows to Linux via Ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, transfer

I need to transfer a backup that I have on windows 10 PC to a PC with Ubuntu MATE.

I read online that it is possible to do this with a LAN cable. I tried connecting the 2 PCs directly with the LAN cable, but I don't know how to check if they are really connected. And I don't know how to access the windows files from Linux.

Can somebody please explain me step by step how to do it?

Comment: Which Windows 0S?

Answer (score 4):

### A reliable solution

- get two ethernet cables and a router
- connect the computers via the router
- make the Ubuntu computer into an ssh server by installing `openssh-server`
- make the Windows computer into an ssh client by installing WinSCP or Filezilla (in Windows)
- connect via WinSCP or Filezilla and transfer the files. You can transfer a whole directory tree.

### A direct connection with one single ethernet cable

#### The Windows end

You can find tutorials via the internet using a search string (without quotes) like "tutorial direct file transfer between two computers via ethernet", for example

https://techwiser.com/how-to-connect-pc-to-pc-lan-cable/

which describes what to do at the Windows end.

#### The Ubuntu end

You can find tutorials via the internet using a search string (without quotes) like "tutorial direct file transfer between two computers via ethernet **linux**" to find for example

https://www.softprayog.in/troubleshooting/connecting-two-computers-with-ethernet-lan-cable

which describes what to do at the Ubuntu end.

---

This is rather complicated, but on the other hand, you will learn a lot about networks.

Comment: I only have one Ethernet cable. I wanted to know if it was possible to transfer files between the 2 pcs connecting them directly with one cable, and if yes how to do it.

Comment: @Cicciopasticcio, Yes it is possible but rather complicated. (A router is doing a good job to make things easier.) I added a couple of links, and you may find links to better tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

**Step one**

I would not recommend to connect the both PCs directly, but rather put a router or a switch in between.

**Step two**

There are several ways to exchange data between a Linux and a Windows PC, such as Samba or others, but there is one which is really easy.

There is a Python package called `magic-wormhole` - https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Install it on both PCs and just do a `wormhole send file` on the one PC, and `wormhole receive` and the other one.

Comment: Interesting :-) This is the first time I read about `magic-wormhole`.

Comment: I only have one ethernet cable. So it's impossible for me to connect both computers to a router

Comment: Maybe one of the two PCs has WLAN access?

Comment: Yes one has WLAN access. I wanted to do it only with the ethernet cable because it's a 60 gb file i want to transfer, and with the wlan it'll take much longer. But if don't find any other solution I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a wire (blue Ethernet cable) you can connect all devices over WiFi including Mac, Windows and Ubuntu. Here is one article on SSHFS:

- [How To Use SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)

Then you can use Nautilus to access the other computer. In my case I did this with my phone and from Nautilus (or the terminal) I can access my phone's files from Ubuntu.

- [How to mount Android external storage over WiFi instead of USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178818/how-to-mount-android-external-storage-over-wifi-instead-of-usb/1179873#1179873)