# How to connect a Ubuntu and a Windows10 using a Ethernet Cable to share files?

Tags: files, file-sharing

I want to transfer all my backed-up files(750GB) which are in a windows10 laptop to my freshly installed Ubuntu system. i have only got a 32GB pen drive and to transfer all the file using it will be a nightmare. Is there a way to connect the two machines?

Both my machines are connected to a router. My windows10 laptop is connected via wireless Wi-Fi and my Ubuntu PC is connected via an Ethernet cable. My PC doesn't have a wireless driver. Another recent problem is, my laptop Ethernet socket doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "same network"? do you mean over Wi-Fi? My PC does not have a wireless card. It is connected with an Ethernet cable with the Wi-Fi router.

Comment: @user68186 my PC doesn't have a Wi-Fi adapter. it is connected via an Ethernet cable with the WI-FI router. but my laptop has a wifi adapter.

Comment: As long as the two PCs are connected to the router, either by WiFi or Ethernet cable, the above should work. Please read the answers.

Comment: @user68186 i have connected the two devices! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both computers connected to the same router, you can use:

1. Ubuntu box as the server: Install `openssh-server`

   1.1. GUI applications: WinSCP, FileZilla

   1.2. Command line scp or (better) rsync from a Unix emulator in Win (that can be MingW, XMobaTerm, etc.)

   1.3. Powershell https://thedarksource.com/powershell-scp-to-transfer-files-between-windows-linux/
2. Windows box as the server: (Will complete depending on your feedback)

If you want a direct connection, here you have a few links.

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251057/can-i-connect-a-ubuntu-linux-laptop-to-a-windows-10-laptop-via-ethernet-cable
2. [Transfer files from Windows to Linux via Ethernet cable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189406/transfer-files-from-windows-to-linux-via-ethernet-cable)
3. https://superuser.com/questions/306682/how-do-i-connect-ubuntu-10-04-and-windows-7-with-an-ethernet-cable
4. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/direct-connect-linux-to-win-via-ethernet-137098/
5. https://linustechtips.com/topic/848807-possible-to-connect-windows-and-linux-pcs-via-ethernet/?tab=comments

Comment: Yes, they are connected to the same router. i will try to work out the aforementioned "thedarksource" article and let you know if i stumble into any problems. Thank you :D